# Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'id<NSCopying>'

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d-ObjC in my app and recently upgraded Xcode to v9.3. Now I have an error in "CCRendererBasicTypes.m" which says

`"Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'id<NSCopying>'"`

Everything else is working fine. This is the part of CCRendererBasicTypes

```
-(id)objectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)options
{
    CCBlendMode *blendMode = [self rawObjectForKey:options];
    if(blendMode) return blendMode;

    // Normalize the blending mode to use for the key.
    id src = (options[CCBlendFuncSrcColor] ?: @(GL_ONE));
    id dst = (options[CCBlendFuncDstColor] ?: @(GL_ZERO));
    id equation = (options[CCBlendEquationColor] ?: @(GL_FUNC_ADD));

    NSDictionary *normalized = @{
        CCBlendFuncSrcColor: src,
        CCBlendFuncDstColor: dst,
        CCBlendEquationColor: equation,

        // Assume they meant non-separate blending if they didn't fill in the keys.
        CCBlendFuncSrcAlpha: (options[CCBlendFuncSrcAlpha] ?: src),
        CCBlendFuncDstAlpha: (options[CCBlendFuncDstAlpha] ?: dst),
        CCBlendEquationAlpha: (options[CCBlendEquationAlpha] ?: equation),
    };

    // Create the key using the normalized blending mode.
    blendMode = [super objectForKey:normalized];

    // Make an alias for the unnormalized version
    [self makeAlias:options forKey:normalized];

    return blendMode;
}
```

The error appears in every line with

```
options[...]
```

Comment: Fixed the problem by deleting the <NSCopying> bit from the method.

Comment: I had the same problem and you just saved me some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Change the first line to

```
-(id)objectForKey:(NSDictionary*)options
```